# MikTex 2.9 Error by using footnote

Tags: errors, footnotes, miktex, output

I have a problem using footnote. If I enter this command, then no pdf-file is created. Here is the last part of die Logfile. At the end it says that some kind of font isn't found. How can I solve this problem?

Part of the Log-File:

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 112.
)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
8267 strings out of 493921
124415 string characters out of 3144832
210228 words of memory out of 3000000
11229 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
28094 words of font info for 68 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
858 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
36i,19n,44p,2931b,460s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:\Users\Wolfgang.Wolfgang-PC\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jkna
ppen\ec\dpi600\eccc1200.pk> <C:\Users\Wolfgang.Wolfgang-PC\AppData\Local\MiKTeX
\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\ecti1200.pk> <C:\Users\Wolfgang.Wolfgan
g-PC\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\ecrm0600.pk> <
C:\Users\Wolfgang.Wolfgang-PC\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen
\ec\dpi600\ecbx1095.pk> <C:\Users\Wolfgang.Wolfgang-PC\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\ecrm1095.pk> <C:\Users\Wolfgang.Wolfgang-PC
\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\ecrm1000.pk>
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ecrm0700): Font ecrm0700 at 600 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{ngerman}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\bibliographystyle{allauthors}
\usepackage[small,normal,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{dipl}
\usepackage[linkcolor=black,
                citecolor=black,
                filecolor=black,
                menucolor=black,
                %pagecolor=black,
                urlcolor=black,
                colorlinks=true,
                pdftitle={title},
                    pdfsubject={Staatsexamensarbeit},
                    pdfkeywords={},
                    pdfauthor={Author}]
                {hyperref}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\pagestyle{empty}

\hyphenation{Hel-lo}

\include{titel}

%\include{abstract}

{
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{headings}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\normalsize \tableofcontents \vfill \eject
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{}{\rule{0cm}{15cm}\vfill\eject}
}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{headings}

\footnote{Test}

\bibliography{Literaturdatenbank_W}
\pagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your MiKTeX installation is missing the CM-Super fonts; you probably can work around the issue by doing `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: If you know that the problem is related to the footnote, why do you show a big example which contains \include and local packages and so can't be compiled? Install with the miktex package manager the cm-super package to get type1 fonts. You will perhaps have to run `updmap` on the command line afterwards.

Comment: Remark: Using type1 fonts (cm-super or lmodern as suggested by egreg) is a (good) work around, it doesn't solve the underlying problem that your system seems not to be able to create the pk-fonts on-the-fly. But as on my system it works fine, I can't tell you what to do about it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.